# How can I shrink a 4-column flexbox layout to 2 columns in Polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0

I have a dashboard I made with Polymer and the flex layout, however there's some issues. Basically I need it to be 4 columns long, but when the screen shrinks I need it to go to 2 columns, and then finally to 1 column. (basically laptop - 4, tablet - 2, phone - 1). Right now it goes 4 to 3 to 2 to 1. How can I achieve the 4 to 2 to 1?

Here's what I currently have:

```
<style>
      #container {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari */
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
</style>
```

and

```
    <div id="container">
        <paper-card heading="ep-gw-ops-node1">
          <div class="card-content">
            <paper-card heading="Temperature" id="temperature" class="blue" style="width: 275px; margin: 2px">
              <div class="card-content">
                <div>
                  <h3 id="tv_temperature" style="color:#fff; text-align: center"> 0 </h3>
                </div>
                <div style="" id="chart_div_0"></div>
              </div>
            </paper-card>

    ...

    ...

    ...

</paper-card>    
</div>
```

I've attached a basic wireframe of what I am trying to accomplish.
If there is a better way to do it without paper-cards I'm more than open to suggestions.

Note* the last column will be lowered so the 'node 1' header will stretch all the way across and the columns will be the same size.

[image: wireframe]

Comment: 4-3-2-1 is expected, I guess you need to use `media queries` with some width / font adjustments if you need it 4-2-1

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>

      .grouph[wide-layout] {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        @apply(--layout-wrap);
        @apply(--layout-center-justified);
      }

      .grouph:not([wide-layout]). .groupv {
        @apply(--layout-vertical);

      }
    </style>
    <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{wide}}"></iron-media-query>
    <div class="grouph" wide-layout$="[[wide]]">
        <paper-card>...</paper-card>
        <paper-card>...</paper-card>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer ({
    is: 'my-element'
  });
</dom-module>
```

This doesn't match your case exactly but the principal is the same.  Use a media query to define a boolean property (in my case `wide`) that can be set for one of your two cases and unset for the other.

Use `wide-layour$="[[wide]]"` on an element that you want to alter dependant on the width.

Use CSS with a selector of `[wide-layout]` or `:not([wide-layout])` to define how a container lays out its children.

You can do it at multiple levels to get whatever re-arrangement you want.